# Creating Multiple Outputs with ffmpeg For HD 1080p 720p 480p

Tags: ffmpeg

Please help me in ffmpeg,,
for multiple outputs with ffpmeg,,
For HD 1080p 720p 480p,, my ffmpeg is working but i wanna outputs multiple

Thanks

Please See the 
[ffmpeg screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqNQr.jpg)

Please can you see the picture i have share [i.stack.imgur.com/SqNQr.jpg] --Thanks a lot for the help it work but i want put on my web can you tell me more which box i put the command,, please see picture (Screenshot)

{ffmpeg-cmd} -i {input} -s 1920x1080 -c:v libx264 1080p {output}.mp4 -s 1280x720 -c:v libx264 720p {output}.mp4 -s 854x480 -c:v libx264 480p {output}.mp4 -s 640x360 -c:v libx264 360p {output}.mp4 -s 426x240 -c:v libx264 240p {output}.mp4 -s 320x180 -c:v libx264 180p {output}.mp4

Answer (score 4):

Daisychain the commands

```
ffmpeg -i input -switches/flags output1 -switches/flags output2 ...
```

e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -s 1280x720 -c:v libx264 720p.mp4 -s 640x360 -c:v libx264 360p.mp4
```